# How to find which answers were marked as spam?

Tags: support, answers, spam, data-explorer, api

Is it possible using SEDE or an API call to find answers marked as spam, and if possible the related user ID?

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? Why do you need this information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API won't help here; it doesn't provide details about deleted posts.

SEDE does in some way; it has a `PostsWithDeleted` table containing some information about deleted posts. You can join it with the `Votes` table looking for spam votes (type 12), [like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1164561/answers-flagged-as-spam).

However, to actually see those posts, you have to have [10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). The PostsWithDeleted table doesn't contain information about the content of the posts, nor the user. Note that the answer could be *flagged* as spam but not actually *marked* as such when a ♦ moderator deleted the post instead of flagging it themselves. Such answers will end up in this query but the -100 reputation penalty would not apply.

A few years ago, I've downloaded all spam posts on Stack Overflow (for [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector#smokedetector)) and uploaded their contents to [GitHub](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/tools/tree/master/revision-downloader/results). It doesn't separate questions from answers though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure this is not possible since deleted posts (including spam deleted ones) are not part of the data explorer. Neither is the reputation history of a user, so identifying users with at least one spam penalty is also not possible.